# How can I filter input to a Scala swing TextField

Tags: scala

Is there a convenient way to add a filter to input to a scala.swing.TextComponent, so that the user can only input integers/floats/whatever? Especially, is there a way to filter pastes into a text field? In Java, I've used a DocumentFilter to do that. I've tried a few variations on this:

```
object inputField extends TextField{

   peer.getDocument.asInstanceOf[AbstractDocument].setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter{

      def insertString(fb: FilterBypass, offs: Integer, str: String, a: AttributeSet){
         if(str.forall((c)=>c.isDigit)) super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a)
      }

      def replace(fb: FilterBypass, offs: Integer, l: Integer, str: String, a: AttributeSet){
         if(str.forall((c)=>c.isDigit)) super.replace(fb, offs, l, str, a)
      }
   })
}
```

Which isn't working. Am I doing that wrong, or does Scala ignore document filters? Is there another way to do this? I might be ok with using an entirely java.swing GUI if that's what it takes.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can attach the DocumentFilter while constructing the TextField (I've never seen examples like that in java). Have you tried creating a normal TextField and attaching the DocumentFilter to it after creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using reactions:

```
import swing._
import swing.event._

object SwingApp extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = new TextField {
      listenTo(keys)
      reactions += { case e: KeyTyped =>
        if (!e.char.isDigit) e.consume
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**:
Oh, I agree, that fits only relatively trivial cases. I've found problem with your original solution: you use Integers where Ints needed, so your methods are just new ones, not implementations of methods of abstract class. Here's how it works for me:

```
contents = new TextField {
  object IntegralFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    override def insertString(fb: FilterBypass, offs: Int, str: String, a: AttributeSet){
       if(str.forall((c)=>c.isDigit)) super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a)
    }    
    override def replace(fb: FilterBypass, offs: Int, l: Int, str: String, a: AttributeSet){
       if(str.forall((c)=>c.isDigit)) super.replace(fb, offs, l, str, a)
    }
  }

  peer.getDocument().asInstanceOf[AbstractDocument].setDocumentFilter(IntegralFilter)
}
```

Notice the use of "override". That's how I got compiler error and corresponding IDE tip, that if I really want to override something with this, I have to change signature.

Comment: No, you can't. If you type Ctrl+V, for instance, that's not a digit, so you can end up with 12garbage34, which isn't an Integer. Also, though my code is meant to be written to filter for integers, I'd really like to be able to filter for floats, such as 123.4, but not 123.4.5.6, or whatever else I want to filter for.

Answer (score 1):

This is class that correctly handles all valid numbers except exponents:

```
class NumberField(initialValue: Double) extends TextField(initialValue.toString) {
  // Note: exponents are not allowed
  val numberFormatException = new NumberFormatException
  listenTo(keys)
  reactions += {
    case event: KeyTyped => {
      try {
        // Don't allow "d" or "f" in the string even though it parses, e.g. 3.5d
        if (event.char.isLetter)
          throw numberFormatException
        // Don't allow string that doesn't parse to a double
        (text.substring(0, caret.position) +
          event.char +
          text.substring(caret.position)).toDouble
      } catch {
        case exception: NumberFormatException => event.consume()
      }
    }
  }

  def value : Double = text.toDouble
}
```